# Ion-tabs are not refreshed when navigates from another page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

The tab view is not refreshed when I redirect from another pane by using navController.setRoot() to the TabsPage. The value in tabs.ts is updated but not reflected in the view.

Please suggest!

Here is my code

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="md-paper"></ion-tab>
 <!--<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="md-paper" (ionSelect)="goToHome()"></ion-tab>-->
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="md-apps"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab *ngIf="selectedItem == 'true'"  (ionSelect)="newBlog()" tabIcon="md-add-circle"></ion-tab>   
</ion-tabs>
```

value of selectedItem is changed but but view is not updated according this changed value

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`*ngIf="selectedItem"`

or:
`*ngIf="selectedItem == true"`. without the quotes.
Giving with quotes means it is a string literal.

Comment: Actually, I Used  this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage); this method from login page redirect to the TabsPage . Value in tabs.ts is updated but tabs.html in not updated. Is this right?  [show]="selectedItem" is also not working

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/ according to this show is an input attribute